# How do I replace a character in an RDD using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have and RDD that looks like this:

```
[['M5126', 'M5416', 'Z4789', 'Z01810', 'S060X6D', 'S9032XA', 'S96912A', 'S72002A', 'S61411A', 'W268XXA', 'Y9269', 'Z23'], ['S62639B', 'M25512', 'M1712', 'M25612', 'M62512', 'S39012D', 'S39012A', 'M25511', 'Z98890', '11', '29', 'Z5189']]
```

How do I replace the commas to tildes so that my RDD looks like this:

```
['M51~ M541~ Z4789~ Z01810~ S060X6D~ S9032XA~ S96912~ S72002A~ S61411A~ W268XXA~ Y9269~ Z23~S62639B~ M25512~ M1712~ M25612~ M62512~ S39012D~ S39012A~ M25511~ Z98890~ 11~ 29~ Z5189']

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: "~".join([str(cd) for cd in row])).reduce(lambda x,y: "~".join([x,y]))
```

But it makes it into one long string.

Comment: the second code snippet is not a valid Python object

Comment: @mck I'm trying to keep everything in spark. I'm hoping to find a way to get that object in spark.

Comment: it's not a valid object in spark or python. do you want a string instead?

Comment: @mck yeah, I believe I do what a string instead.

Comment: what string do you want? can you edit your question to show that string? do you need quotes in your string?

Comment: the commas are part of the representation of a list/collected RDD in Python. Why do you want to change that representation?

Comment: @mck I  updated my question with what I'm looking to get back. The reason I need it like this is for an API call. To put multiple codes in the call and get a response back. I've tried looping through the array but once I hit a code that won't return a response it breaks the entire call. I won't know what codes aren't valid until I see the returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space in the joining string...?

```
result = [rdd.map(lambda row: "~ ".join([str(cd) for cd in row])).reduce(lambda x,y: "~ ".join([x,y]))]
```

which gives

```
['M5126~ M5416~ Z4789~ Z01810~ S060X6D~ S9032XA~ S96912A~ S72002A~ S61411A~ W268XXA~ Y9269~ Z23~ S62639B~ M25512~ M1712~ M25612~ M62512~ S39012D~ S39012A~ M25511~ Z98890~ 11~ 29~ Z5189']
```